# Applicability of Bayes factor to Contingency tables (Chi-Squared)

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test, independence, heteroscedasticity

is it possible to apply the Bayes factor to tests of/for independence/homogeneity (Chi-Square)? You can find a file below. The contingency table shows the data (nominal) found for 9 variants in two groups; the problem with usual frequentist statistics here is that I would probably need to adjust the p-value (Bonferroni) if I checked for each variable independently; and as I have to make several of these tests, I think Bayesian methods seem more adequate. Can you help me out with this issue in any way? How will I need to approach this matter?

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/contingencytab7mwcaof5li.jpg

Comment: What hypothesis exactly do you want to test?

Comment: Any of these
1) The two groups show an equal distribution in terms of the listed variants. (homogeneity)
2) Their is no relation between the variables. (independence) (it would also be possible to test for each variant individually)